# Entity Framework - Efficient eager loading with long chains of dependent objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have an issue, which I assume many professional developers will run into.  My workplace has adopted entity framework.  We use it, and love it.  However, we seem to have run into a very frustrating limitation.

Let's assume you have an object chain as such

A -> B -> C -> D

We are professionals, so these objects have a lot of data, and there is a lot of them in their respective database tables.  It seems EF has a terrible time loading anything past object B.  The SQL queries it generates are really inefficient and not good.  The call would be something like

```
context.objects.include("bObjectName.cObjectName.dObjectName").FirstOrDefault(x => x.PK == somePK);
```

We have gotten around this by explicitly loading objects past that second level with the .Load() command. This works well for single objects. However, when we talk about a collection of objects, we start to run into issues with .Load().

Firstly, there does not seems to be a way to keep proxy tracking of objects in a collection without the virtual keyword. This makes sense because it needs to overwrite the get and set functions. However, this enables lazy loading, and .Load() doesn't map entities when lazy loading is enabled. I find this to be somewhat odd myself. If you remove the virtual keyword, .Load() does automatically link loaded objects to the relevant objects in context.

So here is the crux of my issue. I want proxy tracking, but also want .Load() to map the navigation properties for me. None of this would be an issue if EF could generate good queries. I understand why it can't, it has to be a one show fits all kind of thing.

So to load the third tier of objects I might create a loader function in my service layer that takes all the primary keys of the second tier of objects, and then calls a .Load() on them.
Does anyone have a solution for this? It seems like EF7, or Core 1.0 solves this by:

1. Removing lazy loading entirely, which we could shut off as well, but it would break a lot of older code.
2. Adding a new "ThenInclude" feature, which supposedly increases the efficiency of chaining includes massively.

If turning off lazy loading is the answer, that's fine, I just want to exhaust all options before I waste a lot of time redeveloping a huge webapps worth of service calls.
Does anyone have any ideas? I'm willing to give anything a shot. We are using EF6.

EDIT:  It seems the answer is to shut off lazy loading at a context level, or upgrade to EF7.  I'll change this if anyone else manages to find a solution whereby you can have proxy tracking with forced eager loading on a single object for EF6.

Comment: Have you run SQL Profiler to see what the actual SQL Query is?

Comment: Yes, and I can tell you, literally anytime you chain to a third level, the queries get massively inefficient.  It's because these queries are procedurally generated, so it's understandable.  Understandable as it is, it doesn't work for professional grade software.

One solution is toe save the result of the .Load() and manually set it to the right object.  So In this case, load all C's and set them to B's, but all of the developers here agree, we don't like that.

We like the functionality when virtual is removed, but we also want proxy tracking so we can add to the icollection in object B..

Comment: To my knowledge, you can add a third point to EF 7 advantages. It has at last implemented batched queries, meaning it can bundle many queries in one single call to SQL. This should allow it to issue distinct queries for dependent entities while still causing a single call to SQL, instead of the monstrous single query it was issuing previously. For the performance issue with lazy-loading, this is an EF specific issue due to the lack of a batched lazy loads feature. See [here for an explanation of it with NHibernate](/a/36070727/1178314). It would be a game changer in your case.

Comment: Yes, we did some testing with a console app and EF7, and it MASSIVELY improves performance and query generation with that "ThenInclude" feature.

If this is the answer, then it's the answer, I was just trying to see if anyone else has a solution that doesn't involve so many changes.

I appreciate your responses though.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by *proxy tracking*? It would be *much* clearer if you'd show code that doesn't behave the way you expect (or want). I can't follow your suspected connection between eager vs. lazy loading and tracking. I have no idea what you mean by *.Load() doesn't map entities when lazy loading is enabled*. `Load()` is an eager loading method, how can it be related to lazy loading? And how would it *map* entities? Really, we need code.

Comment: Proxy Tracking is the term that is used.  You can google that.  
  
As far as .Load().  If you have a virtual ICollection, and you call .Load(), and some of the entities loaded map to that ICollection, EF will not put the loaded objects in the ICollection for you.  You have to manually assign them, no proxy tracking.  If you remove virtual, it does, but also removes proxy tracking.  I'll leave the rest to you, code is unnecessary in the explanation of this problem.  I want the auto mapping, and I want proxy tracking.  As others have said EF7 solves this issue.

Comment: Well, "change-tracking proxies" is the much more common name. EF 7 is far from production ready, so I wouldn't recommend using it for production code. If you want change-tracking proxies you can't use it anyway. Too bad you don't want to clarify more. I also wonder why you apparently need to load massive amounts of data. In fact that's where the trouble starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right about chained .Include() statements, [the performance documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh949853.aspx) warns against chaining more than 3 as each .Include() adds an outer join or union. I didn't know about ThenInclude but it sounds like a gamechanger!

If you keep your virtual navigation properties but turn off Lazy Loading on the DbContext

```
 context.ObjectContext().ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

then (as long as Change Tracking is enabled) you can do the following:

```
var a = context.aObjectNames.First(x=> x.id == whatever);

context.bObjectNames.Where(x=> x.aId == a.Id).Load()
```

This should populate a.bObjects

Comment: We wanted to keep lazy loading for all our old code.  It appears this is just not possible.  Lazy loading and change tracking are too tightly knit together.  Which is odd to me, because I can't think of a reason why they should be.  
  
Removing lazy loading involves changing a lot of old (read: bad) code.  This should be done anyways, but time... money.... etc.  
  
I will mark this as the answer, as no one has given a better one for EF6.

Comment: You can eager load without turning off lazy loading on the context. Navigation properties are only loaded when you access them, so you can do your eager loading ahead of time to avoid the lazy loading when the properties are accessed. It really depends on your use case but lazy loading isn't inherently bad, if you're only using a couple of properties from B or C it might make sense to lazy load them rather than pulling back the whole object. Obviously, lazy loading is not your friend if you're iterating through a collection because you end up with the n+1 problem.

Comment: Right, you can eager load on the context with lazy loading enabled.  However, with long chains of collections this generates terrible queries and is very slow with lots of data.  
  
It's a problem I suspect will only turn up in professional software development because of it's unique constraints.  We go into circular arguments of "do this", "but this", etc.  
  
The "ThenInclude" feature of EF7 solves this, but they remove lazy loading anyways.  So, yea...

Basically, I need eager loading, with lazy loading enabled, with change tracking, so I can use .Load() to have EF auto connect objects.